# Библиотеки для работы со звуком Java

Tags: java, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше получать сигнал с аудио разъёма пк для последующей его обработки на java? Есть ли какие - нибудь специальные библиотеки для этой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в этой [статье](https://habr.com/post/191422/) все детально прописано.
Основной код:

```
try {
File soundFile = new File("snd.wav"); //Звуковой файл

//Получаем AudioInputStream
//Вот тут могут полететь IOException и UnsupportedAudioFileException
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

//Получаем реализацию интерфейса Clip
//Может выкинуть LineUnavailableException
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

//Загружаем наш звуковой поток в Clip
//Может выкинуть IOException и LineUnavailableException
clip.open(ais);

clip.setFramePosition(0); //устанавливаем указатель на старт
clip.start(); //Поехали!!!

//Если не запущено других потоков, то стоит подождать, пока клип не закончится
    //В GUI-приложениях следующие 3 строчки не понадобятся
Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
clip.stop(); //Останавливаем
clip.close(); //Закрываем  
} catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException exc) {
exc.printStackTrace();  
} catch (InterruptedException exc) {}
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду библиотеку, которая позволяет проводить обработку сигнала, спектр например получить и тд